# Calculating an integral derived from the convolution of two Fourier transforms

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Let $\sigma>0$ , $1<\alpha\leq 2$, and $-1\leq \beta \leq 1$. I am looking for a closed-form solution (or something near) for the following integral.

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi } \text{PV}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \left(\pi  \delta (u)-\frac{i e^{-i K u}}{u}\right) \left(\mu +\alpha  \beta  \sigma  \tan \left(\frac{\pi  \alpha }{2}\right) \left(\sigma  \sqrt{u^2}\right)^{\alpha -1}-\frac{i \alpha  \left(\sigma  \sqrt{u^2}\right)^{\alpha }}{u}\right) \exp \left(i \left(-\mu  u+\left(\sigma  \sqrt{u^2}\right)^{\alpha } \left(-\frac{\beta  \sqrt{u^2} \tan (\frac{\pi  \alpha }{2})}{u}+i\right)\right)\right) \, du$$
(where PV indicates the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) and $\delta(.)$ is the [Dirac delta function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: Isn't the integrand divergent as $u \to 0$ as $u^{-2}$ and hence non-integrable?

Comment: I revised to add principal value.

Comment: NNT, what are K, i, $\mu$?

Comment: why $\sqrt{u^2}$ and not simply $|u|$ ? Because of complex numbers?

Comment: @BCLC :  I'am wondering if he directly copied  a maple formula without fully understanding it

Comment: @user1952009 Clever XD

Comment: @user1952009 I actually found the formula in a fortune cookie. Does it help?

Answer (score 4):

This is an improper integral near $u=0$. The numerator goes to 1 near $u=0$ but the denominator makes the integral divergent like $\int_0^1 u^{-2}du$ . I suggest revisiting the two original functions whose Fourier transforms yielded your integral to see that they are in fact integrable and that their convolutions therefore is defined. (For example, are the two functions $L^1$ integrable?) Another suggestion: calculate or estimate your integral over the real line but with the interval $[-\delta,\delta]$ removed. Then see if the limit as $\delta\to0$ exists.

Good luck! Sam

PS, to make matters simpler, take $\beta=K=\mu=0$ and $\alpha=2, \sigma=1$. Might be easier to see what's going on in order to determine whether it can exist.

PSS, my comment has become obsolete since the integral keeps changing.

Comment: I reexpressed the integral above by inverting the order in the convolution. But $\frac{\text{sign}(x)}{x^2}$ is integrable by PV, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{\text{sign}(u)}{u^2} du$ and flipping $\int_\epsilon^{\infty}$.